# Javascript prototype problems (with google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, prototype

I'm trying to write a clean GoogleMap.js script.
I have created a js class wich contains gMarker and gInfoWindow and i want to set a "openedInfoWindow" property in its prototype (shared), so i can close it and change it anytime the user clicks on the particular gMarker without stating it as global.

```
function gMarkerWInfo(gMarker,gInfoWindow){
    if(!gMarker || !gInfoWindow)
        return null;
    this.Marker = gMarker;
    this.InfoWindow = gInfoWindow;
}

gMarkerWInfo.prototype.openedInfoWindow = null;

gMarkerWInfo.prototype.openInfoWindow = function(){
    if(this.openedInfoWindow){
        alert(this.openedInfoWindow.getContent());
        //openedInfoWindow.close();
    }
    this.InfoWindow.open(this.Marker.getMap(),this.Marker);
    this.openedInfoWindow = this.InfoWindow;
}
```

The "alert" is for debug purpose and, everytime i click it, it shows me the content of the InfoWindow "linked" to the gMarker i just clicked on. So the "openedInfoWindow" doesn't work how i hope.
Can anyone help me?

PS. Here's the function that i use to create the gMarkerWInfo inside the "GoogleMap" class:

```
this.createMarkerWInfo = function(LatLng,Name,HTML_Infos){
    var gMarker = new google.maps.Marker({  position: LatLng,
                                            animation: this.MarkerAnimation,
                                            map: priv_Map,
                                            title: Name
                                        });
    var gInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:HTML_Infos});
    var gMarkerWInfoWindow = new gMarkerWInfo(gMarker,gInfoWindow);
    google.maps.event.addListener(gMarker,'click', function() {gMarkerWInfoWindow.openInfoWindow();});
    return gMarkerWInfoWindow;
}
```

Comment: The `openedInfoWindow/InfoWindow`-properties are not shared across anything, they've been assigned to the `gMarkerWInfo`-instances, every created marker will have it's own property. You may assign these properties to the map-instance instead to be able to share them across the markers.

Comment: I can even declare a global variable and make it through that way, but i wanted to understand how the prototype-property works.
["But the real power of prototype is seen when multiple instances share a common prototype. Properties of the prototype object are defined once but inherited by all instances which reference it."](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/).
Without the prototype thing i couldn't even use `gMarkerWInfo.prototype.openInfoWindow = function(){...}`, that actually works. So i'm asking, how can i use it for my purpose?

Comment: i found it out, here's the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17139119/2292981)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reading [this article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) i found this out: "*The definition: A function’s prototype property is the object that will be assigned as the prototype to all instances created. [...] It’s important to understand that a function’s prototype property has nothing to do with its actual prototype.*"

So i understood that the `Object.prototype`, wich i was trying to use before, isn't the same as the `Function.prototype`, wich suits my interests.

So here it is, finally working:

```
function gMarkerWInfo(gMarker,gInfoWindow){...}

gMarkerWInfo.prototype.openedInfoWindow = null;

gMarkerWInfo.prototype.openInfoWindow = function(){
   if(gMarkerWInfo.openedInfoWindow)
           gMarkerWInfo.openedInfoWindow.close();
    this.InfoWindow.open(this.Marker.getMap(),this.Marker);
    gMarkerWInfo.openedInfoWindow = this.InfoWindow;
}
```